# How to draw this picture using Tikz (a large diagram with many elements)

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

How to draw this picture using Tikz?

[image]

Here what I've acheived to do.

[image]

1. I can’t align blocks to the right. **solved**
2. How to make crossed out circles? **solved**
3. **How to make curved lines in a drawing?**

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, calc}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth', thick, node distance=2.0em, on grid,
    tt/.style={rectangle, align=center},
    el/.style={circle, draw=black, minimum height=2.6em}
    ]
    \node[rectangle, draw=black, minimum height=11em, minimum width=20em](uop){};
    \node[tt, at={($(uop.north) + (0,-0.75em)$)}](uopt){\bfseries Unified Operating Manual};
    %
    \node[el, below=of uop.north, xshift=-5em](uope1){1};
    \node[el, below=of uop.north](uope2){2};
    \node[el, below=of uop.north, xshift=5em, fill=green](uope3){3};
    %
    \node[el, below=of uop.north, below=of uope1, yshift=-1em](uope4){4};
    \node[el, below=of uop.north, below=of uope2, yshift=-1em](uope5){5};
    \node[el, below=of uop.north, below=of uope3, yshift=-1em](uope6){6};
    %
    \node[el, below=of uop.north, below=of uope4, yshift=-1em](uope7){7};
    \node[el, below=of uop.north, below=of uope5, yshift=-1em](uope8){8};
    \node[el, below=of uop.north, below=of uope6, yshift=-1em](uope9){$N_f$};
    \node (tt) at ($(uope8)!0.5!(uope9)$) {\ldots};
    %
    \node[left=of uope3, xshift=15em](user){\Huge\faIcon{user}};
    \draw[<-, line width=3pt, loosely dotted, green] (uope3) -- (user) node[midway, xshift = 2em, above, black] {Changes};
    %
    \node[rectangle, draw=black, minimum height=11em, minimum width=17em, anchor=north east, below=of uop.south east](man1){};
    \node[tt, at={($(man1.north) + (0,-0.75em)$)}](man1t){\bfseries Manual №1};
    %
    \node[el, below=of man1.north, xshift=-5em](uope11){1};
    \node[el, below=of man1.north](uope21){2};
    \node[el, below=of man1.north, xshift=5em, fill=green](uope31){3};
    %
    \node[el, below=of man1.north, below=of uope11, yshift=-1em](uope41){4};
    \node[el, below=of man1.north, below=of uope21, yshift=-1em](uope51){5};
    \node[el, below=of man1.north, below=of uope31, yshift=-1em](uope61){6};
    %
    \node[el, below=of man1.north, below=of uope41, yshift=-1em](uope71){7};
    \node[el, below=of man1.north, below=of uope51, yshift=-1em](uope81){8};
    \node[el, below=of man1.north, below=of uope61, yshift=-1em](uope91){$N_f$};
    \node (tt) at ($(uope81)!0.5!(uope91)$) {\ldots};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi! Can you specify where the problem is, exactly? The MWE is a good way toward a solution, what is the thing that got you stuck?

Comment: Added problems to the question @Rmano

Comment: Your way of positioning of nodes is wrong. Ti*k*Z will consider only last one ...

Comment: An idea could be to realize the matrices as such (or as `\pics`) and the borders around using the `fit` library.

Comment: The PGF Manual describes in chapter 2.4 Curved Path Construction how it works:

    \draw (node1) .. controls (1,1) and (2,1) .. (node2)

Comment: On a simpler level, there is `\draw (node1) to[bend right] (node2);`  See section 14.13 (page 164).

Comment: @Youra_P: Can you provide a more descriptive title to your question, rather than "How to draw [this]?" The question title shows up in searches, and it would help absolutely nobody when they see that. I recommend highlighting the main problem in the title, even though you're talking about a large diagram with many elements.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Repetitive code can best be avoided using `\pic`s. Therefore a solution using these (in combination with the `matrix` and `fit` libraries and a little friend provided by the `tikzpeople` package):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}  
\usepackage{tikzpeople} % loads tikz
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, fit, shapes.misc}

\tikzset{
    pics/my matrix/.style={
        code={
            \tikzset{my matrix/.cd, #1}
            \matrix (-m) at (0,0) [
                name prefix ..,
                ampersand replacement=\&,
                matrix of nodes, 
                row sep=0.5cm,
                column sep=0.75cm,
                every node/.style={
                    circle, 
                    draw,
                    minimum width=2.5em,
                    inner sep=0pt,
                    text depth=0.1em,
                },
                row 1 column 3/.style={
                    every node/.append style={
                        green!50!black,
                        fill,
                        text=white,
                    }
                },
                my matrix/matrix,
            ] {
                1 \& 2 \& 3 \\
                4 \& 5 \& 6 \\
                7 \& 8 \& $N_{f}$ \\
            };
            \path (-m-3-2) -- (-m-3-3) 
                node[midway] {$\ldots$};
            \node[above] (-header) at (-m.north) {
                \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my matrix/header}
            };
            \node[
                fit={(-m) (-header)}, 
                draw, 
                my matrix/box,
            ] (-box) {};
        }
    },
    my matrix/header/.initial={},
    my matrix/matrix/.style={},
    my matrix/box/.style={
        minimum width=5.5cm
    },
    crossed out/.style 2 args={
        row #1 column #2/.style={
            every node/.append style={
                green!50!black,
                path picture={
                \draw
                    (path picture bounding box.north west) -- 
                    (path picture bounding box.south east) 
                    (path picture bounding box.south west) -- 
                    (path picture bounding box.north east);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \pic (matrix 1) at (0,0) {my matrix={
        header={\textbf{Unified Operating Manual}},
        matrix/.style={
            xshift=-1cm
        },
        box/.style={
            minimum width=7.5cm
        }
    }};

    \pic (matrix 2) at (0,-5) {my matrix={
        header={Manual №1},
        matrix/.style={
            crossed out={2}{3},
            crossed out={3}{3},
            crossed out={3}{2},
        }
    }};

    \pic (matrix 3) at (0,-10) {my matrix={
        header={Manual №2},
        matrix/.style={
            crossed out={2}{2},
            crossed out={3}{3},
            crossed out={3}{2},
        }
    }};

    \pic (matrix 4) at (0,-16) {my matrix={
        header={Manual №$N_{0}$},
        matrix/.style={
            crossed out={2}{3},
            crossed out={3}{1},
        }
    }};

    \path (matrix 3-box.south) -- (matrix 4-box.north) 
        node[midway] {$\vdots$};

    \draw[-stealth] ([xshift=-3.25cm]matrix 1-box.south) |- (matrix 4-box.west);
    \draw[-stealth] ([xshift=-3cm]matrix 1-box.south) |- (matrix 3-box.west);
    \draw[-stealth] ([xshift=-2.75cm]matrix 1-box.south) |- (matrix 2-box.west);

    \node[bob, mirrored, minimum size=1.25cm] (bob)
        at ([xshift=5cm]matrix 1-m-1-3) {User};

    \draw[ultra thick, green!50!black, dashed, -stealth]
        (bob.west) -- (matrix 1-m-1-3)
        node[pos=0.25, above, black] {Changes};

    \draw[ultra thick, green!50!black, dashed, -stealth]
        (matrix 1-m-1-3) to[bend left=70] (matrix 2-m-1-3);

    \draw[ultra thick, green!50!black, dashed, -stealth]
        (matrix 1-m-1-3) to[bend left=70] (matrix 3-m-1-3);

    \draw[ultra thick, green!50!black, dashed, -stealth]
        (matrix 1-m-1-3) to[bend left=70] (matrix 4-m-1-3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do it. Key is this line:

- starts at (uope3)
- moves to side, -20deg,5cm (for a new starting point)
- to (uope31), given out and in-angles

This is often easier than using `..controls..`

```
\draw[->,arr] (uope3) --+(-20:5) to[out=-20,in=0] (uope31);
```

P.S.: You can put more intermediate points, and of course replace - - by to for some more curves.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, calc}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    >=stealth', thick, node distance=2.0em, on grid,
    tt/.style={rectangle, align=center},
    el/.style={circle, draw=black, minimum height=2.6em},
    el2/.style={el, below=of uop.north},
    arr/.style={line width=3pt, loosely dotted, green},
    ]
    \node[rectangle, draw=black, minimum height=11em, minimum width=20em](uop){};
    \node[tt, at={($(uop.north) + (0,-0.75em)$)}](uopt){\bfseries Unified Operating Manual};
    %
    \node[el2, xshift=-5em]             (uope1){1};
    \node[el2]                          (uope2){2};
    \node[el2, xshift=5em, fill=green]  (uope3){3};% <<<
    %
    \node[el, below=of uop.north, below=of uope1, yshift=-1em](uope4){4};
    \node[el, below=of uop.north, below=of uope2, yshift=-1em](uope5){5};
    \node[el, below=of uop.north, below=of uope3, yshift=-1em](uope6){6};
    %
    \node[el, below=of uop.north, below=of uope4, yshift=-1em](uope7){7};
    \node[el, below=of uop.north, below=of uope5, yshift=-1em](uope8){8};
    \node[el, below=of uop.north, below=of uope6, yshift=-1em](uope9){$N_f$};
    \node (tt) at ($(uope8)!0.5!(uope9)$) {\ldots};
    %
    \node[left=of uope3, xshift=15em](user){\Huge\faIcon{user}};
    % ~~~ upper linear vector ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[<-, arr] (uope3) -- (user) node[midway, xshift = 2em, above, black] {Changes};
    %
    \node[rectangle, draw=black, minimum height=11em, minimum width=17em, anchor=north east, below=of uop.south east](man1){};
    \node[tt, at={($(man1.north) + (0,-0.75em)$)}](man1t){\bfseries Manual №1};
    %
    \node[el, below=of man1.north, xshift=-5em] (uope11){1};
    \node[el, below=of man1.north]              (uope21){2};
    \node[el, below=of man1.north, xshift=5em, fill=green](uope31){3};% <<<
    %
    \node[el, below=of man1.north, below=of uope11, yshift=-1em](uope41){4};
    \node[el, below=of man1.north, below=of uope21, yshift=-1em](uope51){5};
    \node[el, below=of man1.north, below=of uope31, yshift=-1em](uope61){6};
    %
    \node[el, below=of man1.north, below=of uope41, yshift=-1em](uope71){7};
    \node[el, below=of man1.north, below=of uope51, yshift=-1em](uope81){8};
    \node[el, below=of man1.north, below=of uope61, yshift=-1em](uope91){$N_f$};
    \node (tt) at ($(uope81)!0.5!(uope91)$) {\ldots};
    
    % ~~~ connectiong both nodes containing "3" ~~~~~~~~~
    %\draw[->,arr] (uope3) -- (uope31); % normal way to do it: straight
    \draw[->,arr] (uope3) --+(-20:5) to[out=-20,in=0] (uope31);
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```